# TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, opencv

I have the code below with cv2 . This code is downloaded from https://github.com/dipakkr/3d-cnn-action-recognition. I want to use cv2.imshow to visualize the frames of the video it get. But I get the following error. What is the problem?
I am doubtful of whether this code is really able to read the video as what is returns as the output is an array of zeros.

```
def video3d(self, filename, color=False, skip=True):

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
        #ret, frame=cap.read()
        #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        nframe = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) #Returns the specified VideoCapture property  ,,Number of frames in the video file

        print (nframe, "nframe")

        if skip:
            frames = [x * nframe / self.depth for x in range(self.depth)]
            print (frames, "frameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees")

        else:
            frames = [x for x in range(self.depth)]
            print (frames, "frameseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee2")

        framearray = []

        for i in range(self.depth):
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frames[i])  #Sets a property in the VideoCapture. ,,0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow(frame)
            print(ret, "reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeettttttttt")
            print(frame ,"frame issssssssssss:")
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.height, self.width))
            print(frame, "frame222 isssssssssssssss")
            #cv2.imshow(frame)
            if color:
                framearray.append(frame)
            else:
                framearray.append(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

        cap.release()
        return np.array(framearray)


X.append(vid3d.video3d(v_file_path, color=color, skip=skip))
```

Error:

```
    main()
  File "3dcnn.py", line 151, in main
    args.output, args.color, args.skip)
  File "3dcnn.py", line 103, in loaddata
    X.append(vid3d.video3d(v_file_path, color=color, skip=skip))
  File "/home/gxa131/Documents/final_project_computationalintelligence/3d-cnn-action-recognition/videoto3d.py", line 34, in video3d
    cv2.imshow(frame)
TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found
```

Answer (score 25):

The first argument to [`cv2.imshow`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow) is the window name, so it's considering the second input `mat` (the image) as missing.  If you don't want to name the window, you can just give an empty string as the first input parameter.

```
cv2.imshow('', frame)
```

Comment: Actually what you suggested works but only window that has no pics appears. Do you know what could be the reason/

Comment: A `cv2.imshow` needs to be followed by a [`waitKey`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) for the image to be displayed, so you could add `cv2.waitKey(1)` right after the `cv2.imshow('', frame)`.

Answer (score 8):

`cv2` didn't the find the *"mat"* (matrix), because you passed the image as the first argument, but the first argument is supposed to be the window name.

```
cv2.imshow(winname, mat)
```

In most cases, you don't care about the window name, so use this:

```
cv2.imshow('', frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result when you change the window name:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = np.full((300, 300, 3), 255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.putText(image, 'some picture', (20, 60),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, [0, 0, 0])

cv2.imshow('custom window name', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

One of the reasons you might want to change window names is to plot many pictures at once, in different windows.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is already answered but would like to add a generic ans to it!

Basically python through this error, when we miss to provide the 2nd parameter to the called function.

When such a error comes just go to the line number pointed in error at output section and check that the function you have called, have all the parameter passed.

Comment: That's not at all a relevant answer and you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Solved by giving the full path of the image to `imread()`